# PHP wildcard redirection based on url paths on database

Tags: php

I'm working on a CMS where there is a section to add the website redirection rules, so basically, there are inputs where you add the Redirect 'FROM' and Redirect 'TO' endpoints and save it to the database so that when you access an URL we have a function that will check if we have the current URL path in the database if so, we will redirect it to the 'TO' endpoint:

[image: cms redirection rules settings]

currently, it only supports the full relative paths redirect and the code is as follows:

```
// Retrieve redirection rule from database
            $redirection = fn_bi_seo_get_redirection_rule($request_uri, Registry::get('runtime.company_id'));
            $redirection_codes = fn_bi_seo_get_redirection_http_codes();
            if (!empty($redirection)) {
                $redirection_message = isset($redirection_codes[$redirection['redirect_code']]) ? $redirection_codes[$redirection['redirect_code']] : '';
                if (isset($redirection['query']) && $redirection['preserve_query_string'] == true) {
                    $redirection['redirect_to'] .= '?' . $redirection['query'];
                }

                if ($addon_settings['redirect_to_non_trailing_slash_url'] == 'Y') {
                    $redirection['redirect_to'] = fn_bi_seo_trim_trailing_slash($redirection['redirect_to']);
                }

                $redirection['redirect_to'] = $redirection['redirect_to'] != '/' ? $redirection['redirect_to'] : '';

                header('HTTP/1.1 ' . $redirection['redirect_code'] . ' ' . $redirection_message);
                $redirect = array(INIT_STATUS_REDIRECT, '/' . $redirection['redirect_to']);
            }
```

So the question is what could be the way to achieve wildcard redirection using PHP by matching the current request URL with data we have in the database:

[image: wildcard image]

Comment: Depends what you actually mean by "wildcard". If that is a classical, stupid star standing for "whatever", then you can simply make a substring match. Or use the `LIKE` oeprator in SQL. The feature would be much more effective if you would use regular expressions to describe the matching patterns, obviously. But that would mean that you have to match the incoming request against _all_ stored redirection rules. _Just like all the http server's redirection modules work ..._

Comment: Thanks, @arkascha, that's exactly what I'm trying to do, can you please post your answer with a simple code example, and I would accept it!

Comment: What is? I pointed out two approaches. And I don't see much more I could add, sorry.

Comment: the first approach regarding the LIKE operator